# Discussing approaches for converting Enum to String

Tags: c++, performance, strings, enum, memory-optimization

I need to convert the ENUM to a respective string value for which I came up with two approaches and I'm trying to see why would a second approach be better than the first one if even in terms of performance and practicality?

Both approaches work. The second requires additional work of having to create an array of struct whereas the first approach merely uses a switch case with hardcoded string values of the corresponding enum.

**First approach**

```
enum class Num : uint32_t
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
};

string EnumToStr(Num num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case Num::One:
            return "One";
            break;
        
        case Num::Two:
            return "Two";
            break;
        
        case Num::Three:
            return "Three";
            break;
        
        
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

int main() 
{
    cout << EnumToStr(Num::One) << endl; // ONE
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Second Approach**

```
#define ENTRY(x) {x, #x}

enum class Num : uint32_t
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    MAX
};


struct Lookup
{
    Num num;
    std::string_view str;
};

constexpr static Lookup table[] =
{
    ENTRY(Num::One),
    ENTRY(Num::Two),
    ENTRY(Num::Three)
};

string_view GetStr(Num num)
{
    uint32_t entryIndex = static_cast<uint32_t>(num);
    uint32_t maxNum = static_cast<uint32_t>(Num::MAX);
    
    if (entryIndex < 0 || entryIndex > maxNum)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return table[entryIndex].str;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << GetStr(Num::One) << endl;   // Num::ONE
    return 0;
}
```

An additional thought that `#define ENTRY(x) {x, #x}` may be not a recommended approach in C++. Are there better ways around it?

***Edit*:**

The following is what I came up with for the memory consumption for respective functions. It seems the second approach consumes more owing to the `struct table` in particular.

**Second Approach:**

- Looking at the [asm](https://godbolt.org/z/c1GsoGqv4), `GetStr()` consumes (0x401147- 0x401120)+1 = 40 bytes
- `sizeof(table)` = 72 bytes
- total = 72 + 40 = 112 bytes

**First Approach:**

- Looking at the [asm](https://godbolt.org/z/nvxdMoEzx), `SwitchCase()` consumes (0x40116d- 0x401120)+1 = 78 bytes

However, doing the following resulted in Second Approach consuming lesser bytes than the First:

- If `const char *` is used instead of `string_view`
- Adding more enum entries

{gcc12.1 + O3}
[166 bytes of First Approach](https://godbolt.org/z/Ec4TbWbeM) vs [96 bytes of Second Approach](https://godbolt.org/z/TTs8dzETh)
(#bytes are calculated at the bottom comments)

**So with more enum entries, does the Second Approach outperform the First Approach?**

Is this one way of determining the performance of functions?

Comment: `using namespace std;`? `std::endl`? You don't have to break out all the bad ideas.

Comment: @Deduplicator I understand the importance of std:: & I assure you I’m using it in the production :)

Comment: Best also avoid it when inviting scrutiny, like here. Do you also know why you should avoid the latter?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is by using [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). These allow you to define the list of enum names and their values exactly once, and then create both the `enum` type and the reverse mapping from that list. For example:

```
#define NUM_LIST \
    X(One, 1) \
    X(Two, 2) \
    X(FourtyTwo, 42)

enum class Num: uint32_t
{
    #define X(name, value) name = value,
    NUM_LIST
    #undef X
};

string EnumToStr(Num num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        #define X(name, value) case Num::name: return #name;
        NUM_LIST
        #undef X
    default:
        return {};
    }
}
```

Once you have written this, then adding a new `enum` value only requires you to add a line to the definition of `NUM_LIST`.

Answer (score 1):

The `const char *` [approach](https://godbolt.org/z/nvxdMoEzx) that you tested is the most performant way to do it, and it is more size efficient than using either `std::string_view` or `std::string`, if you are not using the features of `string_view` or `string` there is no reason to add the overhead involved.

The `Lookup` struct you are creating in the second method isn't necessary for a number of reasons, the first is that the code never uses the Num portion of the struct, the second is that you could use `std::pair` instead.

To answer your comment, yes, because it is an O(1) lookup. This is a size versus speed trade off, however, the executable size of the function will remain the same no matter how large the enum or the array of const char * grow, the executable size of the switch statement will grow with each new case statement. Each new case statement will add a delay the possible solution.

About Deduplicator's comment, prefer `std::cout << "\n";` over `std::cout <<std::endl;` for performance reasons, `std::endl` calls `fflush()` which makes a system call, generally this isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping an example would be given as a part of the solution too. I know std::map & std::unordered_map but are you implying to store the enum,string pair instead and use O(1) lookup time to retrieve the respective string value? An example shall clear things up even more

Comment: @xyf You might want to look at the revised answer.

Comment: Array has a O(1) lookup as well (no linear search is required as shown in the examples) and offers better cache locality than unordered_map. Plus there’s extra overhead associated with hashing of a value which isn’t the case with arrays. I need reasons as to why would you prefer hashtable over array? And again, please provide a code to support your answer

Comment: @xyf I agree with you that an array is a better approach then a map. I changed my answer because of your tests, at first I thought you were asking a how to question in disguise.

Comment: Okay. What about the performance between the approach 1 vs 2? Which one is the preferred approach and why?

Comment: @xyf You generated the code, each case statement turns into an if statement so there is a long chain of if statements, using direct lookup into a table is much faster if there are more than 3 case statements.

Comment: Are you implying switch case approach gets faster if there are more than 3 enum entries/case statements?

Comment: @xyf The exact opposite.

Comment: reason being? Array size also increases in 2nd approach with more enum entries though. &does less memory consumption mean faster performance?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore all the asm considerations because the compiled code will change based on (among other factors):

- the compiler
- the compiler version
- the compiler flags used
- optimizations
- inlining
- caching
- the operating system
- all the other code in the program

In either approach, the compiler could inline everything so that the only space taken up is by the strings themselves. In fact, that's exactly what happens. These two approaches actually result in the same asm when you use the simplest code for both approaches.

First approach:

C++ code:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

enum class Num : uint32_t
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
};

const char* EnumToStr(Num num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case Num::One:   return "One";
        case Num::Two:   return "Two";
        case Num::Three: return "Three";
    }
}
```

asm ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/rexj9eTzx)):

```
EnumToStr(Num):
        mov     edi, edi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR CSWTCH.1[0+rdi*8]
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "One"
.LC1:
        .string "Two"
.LC2:
        .string "Three"
CSWTCH.1:
        .quad   .LC0
        .quad   .LC1
        .quad   .LC2
```

Second approach:

C++:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

enum class Num : uint32_t
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
};

constexpr static const char* table[] =
{
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three"
};

const char* GetStr(Num num)
{
    return table[static_cast<uint32_t>(num)];
}
```

asm ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/aoGn6vdzv)):

```
GetStr(Num):
        mov     edi, edi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR table[0+rdi*8]
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "One"
.LC1:
        .string "Two"
.LC2:
        .string "Three"
table:
        .quad   .LC0
        .quad   .LC1
        .quad   .LC2
```

Both approaches are converted to an array lookup. The only difference is the name of the array. So, the only question is what code is easiest to read, write, and understand. The question of whether to return `const char*`, `std::string_view`, or `std::string` depends on how you expect the function to be used. If I had to guess, `std::string_view` is probably best since it is lightweight (consisting of two pointers) and interacts naturally with `std::string`.

Even including the checks for valid enums results in the same asm:

- [Approach 1 with a default case](https://godbolt.org/z/cKdcesqv8)
- [Approach 2 with an array bounds check](https://godbolt.org/z/b385nzM4G)

##### Scoped enums

The purpose of `enum class` is to create named constants with no implicit conversions to or from the underlying integer type. This allows you to simplify your code because you don't have to handle out-of-bounds values. The only way to get undefined values of `Num` is to use `static_cast<Num>`, and all uses of `static_cast` deserve close scrutiny due to the loss of type information.

##### First approach

This approach is the simplest and the one I like better. It doesn't need any other data besides the function itself. The compiler will generate the lookup table, so why write it yourself? Also, the compiler will help you keep the function and the enum synchronized.

Since a `break` after a `return` is unreachable, we can make this function more compact.

```cpp
string EnumToStr(Num num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case Num::One:   return "One";
        case Num::Two:   return "Two";
        case Num::Three: return "Three";
        default:         return "";
    }
}
```

The `default:` case here is unreachable and not necessary, but not all compilers will allow the `switch` statement without a `default:` to compile without warnings. The `default:` case does protect against accidentally skipping `Num` values, since returning an empty string should have visible consequences in your program. If you ever delete entries from `Num` the compiler will tell you that, for example, `Num::Two` is no longer defined.

##### Second approach

Keeping in mind the purpose of scoped enums, the following check is unnecessary:

```cpp
    uint32_t entryIndex = static_cast<uint32_t>(num);
    uint32_t maxNum = static_cast<uint32_t>(Num::MAX);
    
    if (entryIndex < 0 || entryIndex > maxNum)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

The only way the conditional could evaluate to false is if somebody writes `auto x = static_cast<Num>(42); GetStr(x);`. The check for valid conversions should happen at the point of the `static_cast`, so the check inside `GetStr()` and the entry `Num::MAX` should be deleted. Also, the fact that you cast to an unsigned integer means the `entryIndex < 0` check cannot return false.

```cpp
string_view GetStr(Num num)
{
    return table[static_cast<uint32_t>(num)].str;
}
```

There's another problem with this. Your second approach includes an extra entry in the `enum`: `Num::MAX`. This has a value of 3 and is an out-of-bounds index for `table`. Even the function with the check would have allowed a call of `GetStr(Num::MAX)` to access the `table` with an invalid index. The check should have been `if(entryIndex >= maxNum) { return ""; }`.

Since you only care about the string representation, I don't see why the `Lookup` struct has the `Num` value. It's less typing (and one less function macro) to represent the table as

```cpp
constexpr static const char* table[] =
{
    "Num::One",
    "Num::Two",
    "Num::Three"
};
```

Now, the `GetStr()` function can look like this:

```cpp
string_view GetStr(Num num)
{
    return table[static_cast<uint32_t>(num)];
}
```

The downside of this approach is that you have less protection if you don't keep the `table` and the `Num` enum synchronized. If you have fewer entries in `table` than `Num`, your program will at-best crash after trying to access data beyond the end of the array. If you have more entries in `table` than `Num`, then those extra entries uselessly take up space in the program. This is why I prefer the first approach.

Comment: 1) I agree with the condition in Second approach to check whether index < 0 is redundant cause of unsigned int, however like you said, index > enum entry could be passed in via `static_cast` from the caller which may result in problems, hence the need for `if (i >= Num::MAX)`. 2) lookup tables are generated in both the approaches but memory consumed by the first approach is way more than second approach when enum entries are increased. Shouldn't that be taken into account?

Comment: 1) That's true, but it doesn't help if the table is shorter than the enum. Also, why would a `static_cast<Num>` ever result in an invalid enum value? Anything that is `static_cast` to an enum needs to be checked for validity. The best place to do this is right where the `static_cast` occurs. Otherwise, every function that takes a `Num` will have to do this check. Write your program is such a way that you can always assume that a `Num` is valid. 2) Where would more memory be consumed? All the strings have to be stored somewhere in the program in both cases.

Comment: @xyf [Approach one with more entries](https://godbolt.org/z/f9T4o37nM). And [approach two with more entries](https://godbolt.org/z/1cPYWhKPs). Still the same asm. Both require more memory to store all the strings.

Comment: 1) i'm not saying `static_cast<Num>` would result in an invalid enum, but moreso the condition would be required to ensure the caller does pass the index value that's within the table size. Check the potential issue if index isn't verified: https://cplayground.com/?p=weasel-crocodile-magpie 2) of course memory is required in both cases but my concern was about who consumes *more*

Comment: @xyf 1) I'm saying that any function that receives a `Num` should not have to do this check. The check for a valid value should happen before `static_cast<Num>`. Otherwise, every piece of code that uses a `Num` has to check for valid values. 2) Check the binary generated in the godbolt links. They are exactly the same. They consume the same memory, because the same program is generated.

Comment: 1) but you can't trust how the caller would invoke your function right? (unless it's written by you which may not necessarily be always the case). Just like how I did it, someone else using your API could pass in an integer value and break the function. 2) hm, okay but you're not taking into account the sizeof `table` in the Second approach case. Also if you add an `if` condition inside `GetStr()`, it will change the address by a bit. https://godbolt.org/z/4Trd6zhcv

Comment: @xyf 1) If you feel the need to handle invalid enum values, then the enum serves no purpose. You might as well take an uint32_t as an argument. The use of an enum is a signal to the caller that a strictly limited set of values is expected. If the caller wants to static_cast random values and bypass type safety, that's the caller's risk to take. 2) Both contain lookup tables that contain the same data. In one, the table is named table; in the other, it's named CSWTCH.1. That's the only difference.

Comment: @xyf Let me say again. Studying the compiler output for an isolated function is not a good way to predict performance. In the context of a full program, the complier may generate asm that is completely different from what you see now. The best way to write code is to write simple code that is easy for you to understand. You should only optimize code after you profile the code and prove that this specific function is a bottleneck.

Comment: But simpler may not necessarily be a better approach though. How do you come to conclusion that approach 1 is better than approach 2 or vice versa? It can’t be that a simpler code is going to be more efficient or practical isn’t it?

Comment: @xyf There is no relation between code simplicity and performance. I choose Approach 1 because it is simpler: less code, fewer data structures, and an easy to understand structure. Efficiency and performance should not be a consideration until you can prove that this particular function is slowing down your program by a measurable amount--emphasis on measurement.

Comment: the benchmark test shows otherwise: https://quick-bench.com/q/VjPWPxImGwGITMgMJ8hLv1ysOsY

Comment: @xyf When both functions return a `const char*`, the difference goes away: https://quick-bench.com/q/lyPzNF8UJmb4NAsqr0h8rerulS4

Comment: @xyf When you remove the benchmarking code, the functions compile to identical asm: https://godbolt.org/z/vebKfzPq1

Comment: fair. but still the Second approach turns out to be a bit more fast

Comment: @xyf The difference is nanoseconds--easily caused by different temperatures in the CPU cores during the tests. I'm trying to get you to see that performance is completely irrelevant in deciding how to write this code. Code clarity and complexity are just as important when writing software. My final word on this topic is this: stop looking at your code like a computer and start looking at it like a human being. Write code that's easy for someone to understand when reading it for the first time. Write code that's easy for you to understand after you haven't looked at it for six months.